# Email- Address field should display as mandatory while creating new contact form

Tags: audience-manager

In new contact creation window Email-Address field not coming as mandatory. From Database side it is mandatory but on UI side it is not showing as mandatory. Help me how can I make this mandatory on UI side also.In image you can see all field are mandatory on UI side but Email Address not.[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that's a defect in the product. This particular field is always added and it doesn't check if the field it represents is mandatory or not.

However, it should only be a visual issue in the UI. When saving, you should still get an error if you leave it blank.